# How to return project details (name and other metadata) using rest api?

Tags: java, api, rest

I’m fairly new to REST API and working on a product where client X interacts with n number of servers (Y1, Y2,…Yn) to retrieve different type of data from backend, using POST requests.

Now I also want to retrieve some metadata related to each server (file names, project name etc.) for our internal use-case in client X. Note: This should be a separate request.

How should I implement this using Rest?
Can I use OPTIONS method for this?

I tried implementing this with GET method but not sure if it’s best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are going to retrieve information the GET is the most appropriate. POST instead should be used to 'insert' fresh new datas. I would suggest to take a look at the meaning of all HTTP verbs (POST,GET,PUT,PATCH,DELETE) in order to understand them.